# Google Maps Geocoding API の費用について

Tags: google-maps

Geocodingの費用体系ですが、googleのgsuiteに問い合わせたところ、コアサービスでないため、運営元も分からないという返答でしたため、こちらに質問しております。

1. 無料で利用できる範囲
2. 有料の場合の課金形態

上記2点を教えていただきたいです。
何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Google MapsのGeocoding API、でしょうか？ [Developer Guide  |  Geocoding API  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Comment: はい。その通りです。Google MapsのGeocoding APIです。

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Platform の料金表は次のところにあります。
・ https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Geocodingの料金は、次のようになっています。

```
  0～100,000      $5/1000回
100,001～500,000  $4/1000回
```

Google Maps Platform 全体で無料枠が $200 です。